# How do I customise the display text of a related object in a column in Django Tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using Django Tables 2 to display some information from a list of objects, including a column with a related object.
I'm trying to change the text displayed in the column that shows the related object.

My objects are:

**Job**

```
class Job(StatusModel):
    '''
    Model for jobs
    '''

    STATUS = statuses.JOB_STATUS

    start_time = models.DateTimeField(_('time'), default=timezone.now)
    pickup_address = models.TextField()
    ...
    destination_address = models.TextField()
    ...
    drivers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Drivers.Driver',
        blank=True,
    )
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('job')
        verbose_name_plural = _('jobs')
        ordering = ('start_time',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.start_time.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M') + ' from ' + self.pickup_address

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('job_view', args=[str(self.id)])

    ...
```

**Driver**

```
class Driver(StatusModel):

   ...
    current_job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Current Job'),
        related_name='current_job'
    )
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    ...
```

My table:

```
class DriverStatusListTable(tables.Table):

    user = tables.Column(linkify=True, verbose_name=_('Driver'))
...
    current_job = tables.Column(linkify=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
...
```

I want the "current_job" column to show text different to the returned `__str__` representation of the Job object - namely:
`Job.start_time.strftime('%H:%M') + ' to ' + Job.destination_address,`
but I can't work out how to do this, without changing the `__str__` method on the Job object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [**`Table.render_foo`**](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) to customize the value output.
**Example:**

```
class DriverStatusListTable(tables.Table):
    user = tables.Column(linkify=True, verbose_name=_('Driver'))
    current_job = tables.Column(linkify=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Driver

    def render_current_job(self, value):
        return "Use 'value' parameter here and return useful resposne"
```